Why does the information_schema.table_privileges in Redshift not support the truncate type?
I want to query the select, insert, update, delete, and truncate privileges for users on tables.
However, the table_privileges view does not show the truncate privilege.
When I try to include the truncate type in the makeaclitem() function, an error occurs.
Is there an alternative?

SELECT u_grantor.usename::information_schema.sql_identifier AS grantor, 
        grantee.name::information_schema.sql_identifier AS grantee, 
        current_database()::information_schema.sql_identifier AS table_catalog, 
        nc.nspname::information_schema.sql_identifier AS table_schema, 
        c.relname::information_schema.sql_identifier AS table_name, 
        pr."type"::information_schema.character_data AS privilege_type 
FROM pg_class c, pg_namespace nc, pg_user u_grantor,
(SELECT pg_user.usesysid, 0, pg_user.usename FROM pg_user ) grantee(usesysid, grosysid, name), 
(((((( SELECT 'SELECT'::character varying
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'DELETE'::character varying)
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'INSERT'::character varying)
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'UPDATE'::character varying)
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'REFERENCES'::character varying)
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'TRUNCATE'::character varying)
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'TRIGGER'::character varying) pr("type")
        WHERE c.relnamespace = nc.oid 
AND c.relkind = 'r'::"char"
AND aclcontains(c.relacl, makeaclitem(grantee.usesysid, grantee.grosysid, u_grantor.usesysid, pr."type"::text, false))


SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: unrecognized privilege type: "TRUNCATE"


I used this query with union all.
/* UNION ALL */
select '' as grantor,
            tableowner as owner,
            usename as grantee,
            schemaname as schemaName,
            tablename as tableName,
            'TRUNCATE'::information_schema.character_data as privilege
from (
        SELECT  usename,
                schemaname,
                tablename,
                tableowner,
                has_table_privilege(usename, schemaname || '.' || tablename, 'truncate') as truncate
        FROM    pg_tables, pg_user
        WHERE   schemaname <> 'pg_internal'
) A
WHERE A.truncate

